# Reset configuration in enterprise architect

Tags: enterprise-architect

I added some artifacts to appears as parts of a bigger component.

When I drag the artifact to the component it show a popup asking if I want to add it as part or port. Everithing works fine.

Then I chose an option to not show the popup again. How I undo this? I want to add things as parts of my component.

I'm using Enterprise Architect version 7.1.831

Comment: You need to upgrade to a more recent EA release in order to get a valid answer!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the poster uses a version of EA which is way outdated.

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl-drag an element from the project browser. This makes EA show the dialog again and you can change the options inside this dialog back to what you need.

Comment: Did not work, it shows the dialog to paste the element in the diagram, but I can not add the artifact in the component.

With a right click in the component there is a option to add embedded element as Port, but there is no option as Part. 

I'm trying to find where EA saves this user defined configuration to reset is

Comment: Just notice that you use version 7. We are at 12!! I could support you back to 9.5 but not this outdated version!